# Count row by current column and time

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with query. I want to count the occurrence of a specific phrase in a given column at specific time.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prodId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookingAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `equipmentType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `shippingAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I have a working query checking the number of inventory receipt :

```
SELECT g1.equipmentType,COUNT(*) as count FROM table g1
WHERE g1.shippingAt IS NULL AND 
g1.bookingAt BETWEEN :from AND :to GROUP BY g1.equipmentType
```

But I do not know how to construct a query for products sent :(
Sample data in table:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `prodId`, `bookingAt`, `equipmentType`, `shippingAt`) VALUES
(1, 9911199, '2018-04-05 09:30:03', 'Type1','2018-04-05 14:00:00'),
(2, 9911100, '2018-04-05 08:00:00', 'Type1','2018-04-05 14:10:00'),
(3, 1234563, '2018-04-05 10:05:40', 'Type2', NULL);
```

Working result(booking) with my query:

```
array [
  0 => array [
    "equipmentType" => "Type2"
    "count" => "1"
  ]
```

Expected result (shipping):

```
array [
  0 => array [
    "equipmentType" => "Type1"
    "count" => "2"
  ]
```

Comment: give us a sample data and the result you expect.

Comment: isn't there any product table?

Comment: @gmarif no,this is only one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 'NOT' to the test for NULL on shippingAt will give you shipped products.

```
SELECT g1.equipmentType,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM table g1
WHERE g1.shippingAt IS NOT NULL 
AND g1.bookingAt BETWEEN :from AND :to 
GROUP BY g1.equipmentType;
```

This query is based on the table and data you supplied but how that relates to the title or what you were asking at the start of the question is a mystery.

Comment: Unfortunately, this query does not return  result :(

Comment: It does if you put in some dates that match the data you supplied. Try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232fc0/2

Comment: You're right. It's my mistake. I've been reading this code too long :D

Comment: @grda So, how did that relate to the rest of the question?